# Axonframework, how to use MessageDispatchInterceptor with reactive repository

Tags: kotlin, axon, axon-framework

I have read the set-based [consistency validation blog](https://axoniq.io/blog-overview/set-based-validation) and I want to validate through a dispatch interceptor. I follow the example, but I use reactive repository and it doesn't really work for me. I have tried both block and not block. with block it throws error, but without block it doesn't execute anything. here is my code.

```
class SubnetCommandInterceptor : MessageDispatchInterceptor<CommandMessage<*>> {

  @Autowired
  private lateinit var privateNetworkRepository: PrivateNetworkRepository

  override fun handle(messages: List<CommandMessage<*>?>): BiFunction<Int, CommandMessage<*>, CommandMessage<*>> {
    return BiFunction<Int, CommandMessage<*>, CommandMessage<*>> { index: Int?, command: CommandMessage<*> ->
      if (CreateSubnetCommand::class.simpleName == (command.payloadType.simpleName)){
        val interceptCommand = command.payload as CreateSubnetCommand
        privateNetworkRepository
          .findById(interceptCommand.privateNetworkId)
          // ..some validation logic here ex.
          // .filter { network -> network.isSubnetOverlap() }
          .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(IllegalArgumentException("Requested subnet is overlap with the previous subnet.")))
          // .block() also doesn't work here it throws error
         // block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-
      }
      command
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subscribing to a reactive repository inside a message dispatcher is not really recommended and might lead to weird behavior as underling ThreadLocal (used by Axox) [is not adapted to be used in reactive programing](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/707#issuecomment-312598384.)

Instead, check out [Axon's Reactive Extension](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/extensions/reactor/reactive-gateways) and reactive interceptors section.

For example what you might do:

```
reactiveCommandGateway.registerDispatchInterceptor(
        cmdMono -> cmdMono.flatMap(cmd->privateNetworkRepository
      .findById(cmd.privateNetworkId))
.switchIfEmpty(
Mono.error(IllegalArgumentException("Requested subnet is overlap with the previous subnet."))
.then(cmdMono)));
```

Comment: thanks for the advice, btw I don't see any ReactorCommandBus in the extension should I use ReactroCommandGateway instead?

Comment: yes, there are only reactive gateways supported